# How do i make a website that creates a html table using javascript prompts?

Tags: javascript, variables, html-table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var r = prompt ("how many rows ?");
    var c = prompt ("how many columns ?");
    var red = prompt ("how red ?");
    var green = prompt ("how green ?");
    var blue = prompt ("how blue ?");
    document.write('<table style="width:100%"     bgcolor="'+red+''+green+''+blue+'">');
    for(var r = i; i > -1; i--){
        document.write('<tr>');
        for(var c = i; i > -1; i--){
            document.write('<th></th>');
        };
        document.write('</tr>');
    };
    document.write('</table>');

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with my code ? I answer all the prompts but nothing happens on the screen. My professor said that i would need a for loop inside of an another for loop, what am i missing?

Comment: doc.write does its writing "right there". Which means you're spitting out your table tables into that exact spot of your document - tables are `<body>` content, but you're spitting that out in the document's `<head>`.

Comment: So should i move the entire document.write('<table style="width:100%" >');
  for(var r = i; i > -1; i--){
   document.write('<tr>');
   for(var c = i; i > -1; i--){
    document.write('<th></th>');
   };
   document.write('</tr>');
  };
  document.write('</table>');part to body ?

Comment: why don't you try it? while we're happy to help, you should be doing your own homework...

Comment: well it doesn't work D: and i checked the examples we did at the lecture all of the "document.write" code is written in the head section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple corrections:

1. Don't use document.write multiple times, since each call will overwrite the contents of the body.
2. Your iterator assignment logic was backwards - assign `i = r`, not `r = i`, since the value of the expression (variable in this case) on the right side gets assigned to the variable on the left side.
3. You need to use a separate iterator variable (e.g. `j`) for the inner `for` loop, otherwise it would interfere with the outer loop.
4. The iterator conditions are off by 1. If you are going to decrement from the max number (of rows, columns) then iterate while i/j are greater than 0, not -1

```js
    var r = prompt ("how many rows ?");
    var c = prompt ("how many columns ?");
    var red = prompt ("how red ?");
    var green = prompt ("how green ?");
    var blue = prompt ("how blue ?");
    var html = '<table style="width:100%"    bgcolor="'+red+''+green+''+blue+'">';  
    for(var i= r; i > 0; i--){        
      html += '<tr>';
        for(var j = c; j > 0; j--){
            html +='<th></th>';
        };
        html += '</tr>';
    };
    html +='</table>';
    document.write(html);
   //or else instead of document.write, use something like the line below :       
   //document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body id="container">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer this worked. Sorry i can't vote useful bc of my reputation :P

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that you are not initializing the i variable (there is no 'var i' in your code).  This variable is the index variable for your loop, set it to the row/column input variable that the user entered.

Also, when you put a nest loops don't try to reuse the index variable (i).

And work through the logic of the loop iterator, you actually want the loop to run to condition i > 0

Change the loops to something like:

```
for(var i = r; i > 0; i--){
    document.write('<tr>');
    for(var j = c; j > 0; j--){
...
```

And check on what the th tag is in html, you really want td

And then you will still not see the table you just created because there is no content in the 'cells', so you can add content or you can see the table when you use the browser developer tools.